# Import csv file to database - values with comma

Tags: php, mysql, csv, import

I'm trying to import a csv file to my database. It's working but the problem is I have a column, namely "address1" and "address2" which may have commas. Example is:

```
194 Chavez compound, Something City
```

What's happening is194 Chavez compound is in the "address1" and Something City is in "address2". The whole address should be in "address1" only.

This is my code on importing in my database:

```
    do { 
        if ($data[0]) { 
            mysql_query("INSERT INTO awb (recNAME, company, address1, address2, city, province, postalCODE, contactNO, email, commodity, type, weight, length, width, height, decVAL, specINSTRUC, shipREF, payMETHOD, packNO, trackNO) VALUES 
                ( 
                    '".addslashes($data[0])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[1])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[2])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[3])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[4])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[5])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[6])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[7])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[8])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[9])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[10])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[11])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[12])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[13])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[14])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[15])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[16])."', 
                    '".addslashes($data[17])."',
                    '".addslashes($data[18])."',    
                    '".addslashes($data[19])."',                    
                    '".addslashes($data[20])."' 
                ) 
            "); 
        } 
    } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'"));
```

Comment: Why not use [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/load-data.html) or [**mysqlimport**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysqlimport.html)?

Comment: In any event, if fields containing the field delimiter are not enclosed (e.g. within quote `"` characters) or such delimiters within fields are not escaped in some way (e.g. with backslash ``\`` characters), how can any parser *possibly* know whether a given delimiter is part of a field or not?

Comment: I'm new in php. I just started playing around in databases and excel files. I haven't tried anything else. So I guess I'll try using LOAD DATA INFILE or mysqlimport. about the second comment, honestly, I didn't understand a few words like delimeter and parser.

Comment: If it's a proper csv file, then any value containing a comma should be enclosed in quotes.... you're saying a single quote in your fgetcsv() call; make sure it is a single quote and not a double quote

Comment: The "field delimiter" is the character or characters which separate the "fields" (or "columns" or "values") within your file: in your case, the "field delimiter" is comma `,`.  A parser is a program which reads a file and understands how the data within it should be divided up.

Comment: aaahh. now I get it. thanks eggyal! I also found an example which uses LOAD DATA INFILE. I guess I should try it. thanks again. :)

Comment: I tried the LOAD DATA INFILE, still the same.

Comment: if I'm going to use mysql_real_escape_string(), where should I put it in the program?

Comment: @nicole101: In this case, you should use `mysql_real_escape_string()` instead of `addslashes()`.  However, I would recommend that you instead focus on getting `LOAD DATA` or **mysqlimport** to work for you.

Comment: thanks! although still the same. hahaha. Next option mysqlimport.

Comment: final question, how can I add "" in my delimeter?

Answer (score 1):

As one of the commentors suggested, try using LOAD DATA INFILE instead:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '[file name]' INTO TABLE '[table name]'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

If your CSV file has a header row, you'll also want to add this clause: IGNORE 1 LINES.